# How to use a logical operator in WikiText to select a tiddler with one OR another tag?

Tags: tiddlywiki, wikitext

The TiddlyWiki documentation provides an [example of the tag operator](https://tiddlywiki.com/#tag%20Operator%20(Examples)):

```
[tag[task]]
```

This selects all tiddlers that have been tagged as *task*.

How though would one select all tiddlers tagged with one OR another tag; so for instance I want to select all tiddlers that are tagged either *dog* or *cat*?  None of the below attempts succeed:

```
[tag[cat]||[dog]]
[tag[cat]OR[dog]]
[tag[cat, dog]]
```

For context, I'm looking to use this within a list, along the lines of:

```
<$list filter="[tag[cat]||[dog]]">
<$view field="title"/>
</$list>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A bit late but in case it's still useful...*

There are various ways to combine the results of different lists, and in this case one just needs the simple union of lists which is represented with a space between two filter expressions:

```
<$list filter="[tag[cat]] [tag[dog]]">
<$view field="title"/>
</$list>
```

The document about filters is rich but a bit messy, I think that this is explained in ["Introduction to filter notation"](https://tiddlywiki.com/#Introduction%20to%20filter%20notation) but there are other relevant parts in ["Filter expression"](https://tiddlywiki.com/#Filter%20Expression), also [here](https://tiddlywiki.com/#Dominant%20Append) and possibly in other places.

Comment: I think the syntax is [tag[cat]tag[dog]]?

Comment: @rmrf no, when filters are concatenated like in your option it means AND: `[tag[cat]tag[dog]]` would return the tiddlers which have both tags 'cat' and 'dog'. OR can be expressed with two lists of filters separated by a space, so my option would return tiddlers which have either 'cat' or 'dog' (or both).